# WCF and querystring param sensitivity

Tags: wcf, web

Usually you do consider querystring params as case sensitive in most frameworks in terms of the backend matches.

But I just tried in WCF, is there some built-in hack that allows incoming querystring params to be case insensitive??

Comment: Hmmm... The `http` spec says that the query string should be case sensitive.

Comment: @ClarkKent Unfortunately `HttpRequest.QueryString[key]` is not which has apparently led to some bad programming practices (my own included).